CDN Conditional logging in fastly
I'm trying to conditionally log a header in datadog, through fastly with something like:
"http": {
        "method": "%{req.request}V",
        "url": "%{json.escape(req.url)}V",
        "useragent": "%{User-Agent}i",
        "this_is_true": "%{req.http.this-is-true}V. <--- How can I make conditional?
    }

Basically in the vcl I have an if block that checks a condition and if true, sets this_is_true header. But I only want to log this header in datadog if it's true. Any ideas?
